# Java binary method for GCD infinate loop

Tags: java, infinite-loop, greatest-common-divisor

I'm using the Binary Method to calculate the GCD of two fractions, the method works perfectly fine, except for when I subtract certain numbers from each other.

I'm assuming it's because, for instance, when I subtract 2/15 from 1/6, the GCD has a repeating number or something like that, though I could be wrong.

```
        //The following lines calculate the GCD using the binary method

        if (holderNum == 0) 
        {
            gcd = holderDem;
        }
        else if (holderDem == 0) 
        {
            gcd = holderNum;
        }
        else if ( holderNum == holderDem)
        {
            gcd = holderNum;
        }

        // Make "a" and "b" odd, keeping track of common power of 2.
        final int aTwos = Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(holderNum);
        holderNum >>= aTwos;
        final int bTwos = Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(holderDem);
        holderDem >>= bTwos;
        final int shift = Math.min(aTwos, bTwos);

        // "a" and "b" are positive.
        // If a > b then "gdc(a, b)" is equal to "gcd(a - b, b)".
        // If a < b then "gcd(a, b)" is equal to "gcd(b - a, a)".
        // Hence, in the successive iterations:
        //  "a" becomes the absolute difference of the current values,
        //  "b" becomes the minimum of the current values.
        if (holderNum != gcd)
        {
            while (holderNum != holderDem) 
            {
                    //debuging
                    String debugv3 = "Beginning GCD binary method";
                    System.out.println(debugv3);
                    //debugging
                    final int delta = holderNum - holderDem;
                    holderNum = Math.min(holderNum, holderDem);
                    holderDem = Math.abs(delta);

                    // Remove any power of 2 in "a" ("b" is guaranteed to be odd).
                    holderNum >>= Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(holderNum);
                    gcd = holderDem;
            }
        }           

        // Recover the common power of 2.
        gcd <<= shift;
```

That is the code that I'm using to complete this operation, the debugging message prints out forever.

Is there a way to cheat out of this when it gets stuck, or maybe set up an exception?

Comment: Have you tried printing out something useful, like the values of "holderNum" and "holderDem"? That way you could see what the numbers are doing, rather than guessing at it.

Comment: How is "b" guaranteed to be odd? For what values of `holderNum` and `holderDem` is it entering an infinite loop?

Comment: Yes, when I print those out, using the example given, holderNum stays at -3 while holderDem keeps increasing, 1195095 was where it got before I force quit it.

Comment: For what values? It works for me.

Comment: The example given, for example 2/15 minus 1/6. Or 1/1 minus 1/1. 

But if I put a break in there, it works just fine, which I guess works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with negative values — when one of them is negative, `holderNum` will always take on the negative value (being the min); `holderDem` will become postive, so `delta` equal to a negative less a positive equals a lesser negative. Then `holderDem = abs(delta)` is a greater positive and keeps increasing. You should take the absolute value of both of them before entering the loop.

E.g.:

`holderNum = -1` and `holderDem = 6`
Iteration 1:

```
delta = holderNum - holderDem = -1 - 6 = -7
holderNum = Math.min(holderNum, holderDem) = Math.min(-1, 6) = -1
holderDem = Math.abs(delta) = Math.abs(-7) = 7
```

Iteration 2:

```
delta = holderNum - holderDem = -1 - 7 = -8
holderNum = Math.min(holderNum, holderDem) = Math.min(-1, 7) = -1
holderDem = Math.abs(delta) = Math.abs(-7) = 8
```

etc., etc., etc.

Comment: I can see the problem there, but even if I put in to take the abs vale of Num and Dem, in or out of the loop, it still iterates infinitely. 
I had to add `while (holderDem != 0 && holderNum != holderDem && holderNum != 0)`

Comment: Weird. The only reason `holderNum` or `holderDem` should ever be `0` is if they start with that value — in which case they should be caught at the beginning (and now I notice that the line `if (holderNum != gcd)` should also test `holderDem`) — or if they are equal at the beginning of the loop — in which case the loop should stop. If you're taking the absolute values at the begninning of this code, I don't see why it should be entering an infinite loop.

Comment: Neither do I. It's really weird, I think some Python got into my Java.